# C# delete first numbers and spaces, renumber ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

As you can see in the picture, I want to remove the numbering. This is sometimes special and you can see that there are a few spaces after the number. Between 1-9 there are usually 3, but sometimes 4. Between 10-99 there are 2 or sometimes 3. How can I remove them and make a new numbering? Thanks.

I tried:

```
private void button43_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var empty = " ";
            for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (listBox1.Items[i].ToString().Contains(empty))
                {
                    listBox1.SetSelected(i, true);
                    var new = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    new = new.Substring(4);
                    listBox1.Items.Insert(listBox1.SelectedIndex, new);
                    listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
                    listBox1.ClearSelected();
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this? Have you tried any of the string manipulation methods? Please provide sample content as text.

Comment: Could you provide the *desired result*, please?

Comment: @dimnnv Where did I upload a code as an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is wrong, because you are inserting data, and therefore moving everything up. You would need to either flip the remove and insert, or add 1 to the `RemoveAt`.

Even better, just modify it in place.

And you don't need to select anything.

```cs
if (listBox1.Items[i].ToString().Contains(empty))
{
    listBox1.Items[i] = listBox1.Items[i].ToString().Substring(4);
}
```

Comment: You right, I don't need to select all. Works fine and fast with .TrimStart. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You could use the String.TrimStart(char[]). TrimStart(char[]) removes all mentioned chars from the start of a string until the first char which isn't mentioned.

```
if (listBox1.Items[i].ToString().Contains(empty))
{
    listBox1.SetSelected(i, true);
    var new = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
// Assuming i is the new number.
    new =i.ToString() + " " + new.TrimStart(' ', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0');
    listBox1.Items.Insert(listBox1.SelectedIndex, new);
    listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
    listBox1.ClearSelected();
 }
```

Source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trimstart?view=net-7.0

I also recommend not to use the "new" as a name for anything.